# Ajax load is only working for a single instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a button that loads in some form elements, but when the user clicks the button more than once it doesn't add the data again. It only seems to work 1 time. I need it to add the ajax every time the user clicks the button.

```
    $(".add-media-item").on("click", function () {
            $( ".media-item-zone" ).load( "/includes/add-media-item");
    });
```

Comment: are you sure it's not working? this is loading the same page into the same div(s), so things might not look different when you click the button a second time. check your network tab to be sure.

Comment: Could you add a little more code?

Comment: It may just use the cache.  Put a random string at the end of the URL.

Comment: Where do you expect the data to be added? How do you expect this to work? My guess is that it is working just fine as it is coded, but it is not coded how you expect it to work.

Comment: epascarello is that not true of every bug ever written? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.load(...)` will replace the content that's there with the content you get from the server. You probably need to use `.append()`, which also means you'll have to write a more custom ajax request handler. Something like:

```
$(".add-media-item").on("click", function () {
        $.get("/includes/add-media-item", function(response) {
          $( ".media-item-zone" ).append(response);
        });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to clear ".media-item-zone" at the top of your click handler. Also if .add-media-item is within .media-item-zone, it might be getting wiped by the load function (seems unlikely as it would throw an exception, so be sure to check your js console!)

Comment: *'Try to clear ".media-item-zone" at the top of your click handler'* that is already happening by using `.load(url)`